# onchange not always working

Tags: javascript, mootools, onchange

I'm making a table where i present 'X' rows of data in various pages... this 'X' rows could be 10, 20, or 30 so i made a select like this

```
<select id="lala" name="lal">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

and my script(i'm using mootools) is this

```
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('lala').addEvent(
   'change', function() { 
   alert('Has cambiado el campo select');
   }); 
   });
```

my problem is that the event is not working in the first and last page but is working in the rest... example: i have 10 pages, and in page 1 and 10 the event do nothing and in pages 2 to 9 does work....

note: sorry for my bad english

edit: this is my table(a part but the important)

```
 <table id="rounded-corner" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="rounded-r">Dia <img class="difcursor" src="Imagenes/<?php echo $a ?>.png" id="ordendia" /></th>
                <th>Hora</th>
                <th>Desde <img class="difcursor" src="Imagenes/<?php echo $b ?>.png" id="ordensrc" /></th>
                <th>Destino <img class="difcursor" src="Imagenes/<?php echo $c ?>.png" id="ordendst" /></th>
                <th>Estado <img class="difcursor" src="Imagenes/<?php echo $d ?>.png" id="ordenest" /></th>
                <th class="rounded-l">Duracion <img class="difcursor" src="Imagenes/<?php echo $e ?>.png" id="ordendur" /></th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
```

```
$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY $bot $orden LIMIT $g, $cantm";
    $result2 = $dbh->prepare($consulta2);
    $result2->execute();



foreach ($result2 as $valor) {
             $separar = explode(' ',$valor['calldate']);
             $dia = explode('-',$separar[0]);
             switch ($valor['disposition']){
                case "ANSWERED":
                    if ($valor['lastapp']=="VoiceMail"){
                        $estado="Buzon de Voz";
                        }
                    else{
                        $estado="Contestado";
                        }
                    break;
                case "NO ANSWER":
                    $estado="No Contestado";
                    break;
                case "BUSY":
                    $estado="Ocupado";
                    break;
                }
                $minutos = 0;
                $horas = 0;
                while ($valor['duration'] > 60){
                    $minutos++;
                    $valor['duration'] -= 60;
                }
                while ($minutos > 60){
                    $horas++;
                    $minutos -=60;
                }
                if ($valor['duration'] < 10){
                    $segundos = "0".$valor['duration'];
                }
                else { 
                    $segundos = $valor['duration']; 
                }
                if ($minutos < 10){
                    $minutos = "0".$minutos;
                }
                if ($horas < 10){
                    $horas = "0".$horas;
                }


            ?>

            <tr>
            <td><?php echo "$dia[2]-$dia[1]-$dia[0]"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$separar[1]"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$valor[src]"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$valor[dst]"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$estado"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$horas : $minutos : $segundos"; ?></td>
            </tr>
  <tfoot>
          <tr>
                <td colspan=5 class="rounded-foot-left"><a href="lrecibidas.php?call=<?php echo $opcion; ?>&bot=<?php echo $bot; ?>&orden=<?php echo $orden; ?>&bot2=primera&pag=<?php echo $act; ?>&cantm=<?php echo $cantm; ?>"><?php echo $imag; ?></a>
                                                        <a href="lrecibidas.php?call=<?php echo $opcion; ?>&bot=<?php echo $bot; ?>&orden=<?php echo $orden; ?>&bot2=atras&pag=<?php echo $act; ?>&g=<?php echo $g; ?>&cantm=<?php echo $cantm; ?>&g=<?php echo $g; ?>"><?php echo $imag2; ?></a>
                                                         Pagina <?php echo $act ?>/<?php echo $cantp ?>
                                                        <a href="lrecibidas.php?call=<?php echo $opcion; ?>&bot=<?php echo $bot; ?>&orden=<?php echo $orden; ?>&bot2=adelante&pag=<?php echo $act; ?>&g=<?php echo $g; ?>&cantm=<?php echo $cantm; ?>"><?php echo $imag3; ?></a>
                                                        <a href="lrecibidas.php?call=<?php echo $opcion; ?>&bot=<?php echo $bot; ?>&orden=<?php echo $orden; ?>&bot2=ultima&pag=<?php echo $act; ?>&cantm=<?php echo $cantm; ?>&g=<?php echo $g; ?>"><?php echo $imag4; ?></a>
                </td>
                <td colspan=2 class="rounded-foot-right">
                <form>  
                    <select id="lala" name="lal">
                      <option value="10">10</option>
                      <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
                      <option value="30">30</option>
                    </select>
                </form> 
            </td>

          </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

the images are arrows to go from a page to another(and if anyone knows how to pass a variable from php to JS without using the URL i'm all ears :) ) 
the thing is i'm using javascript to order the table as i want, and works in all pages...

to do the pagination i'm using this:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT count(*) AS cantidad FROM table");
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row["cantidad"]>$cantm){
    ++ $cantp;
    $row["cantidad"]-=$cantm;
    }
    ++ $cantp;
    switch ($bot2){
        case "primera":
            $g = 0;
            $act = 1;
        break;

        case "atras":
            $g -= $cantm;
            $act -= 1;
        break;

        case "adelante":
            $g += $cantm;
            $act += 1;
        break;

        case "ultima":
            $aux = $cantp - 1;
            $g = $aux * $cantm;
            $act = $cantp;
        break;
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with your select, but rather with something else breaking your javascript. Can we see the table, and what are you using to create a paginated table?

Comment: there is it.... i hope is everithig you need(the rest of the code doesn't do anything to the table) i'm going crazy with this

Comment: Haha Don't succumb to despair! We'll help you man.

Comment: You are missing the <tbody>. The best way for us to help you is this:  run the page, take the rendered HTML for the table and paste it in a jsFiddle, include the tablesorter plugin in the jsFiddle and share the link. It is hard to debug without the rendered html table. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: first: http://jsfiddle.net/6VTEd/ <-- here is it.. but there is a problem and that is the images.. they swap when i order the table(so the person can see if is asc or desc) and the functions don't work(when you see it you will understand) without them

second: i'm a girl hahaha don't take it personally but it's funny that you always referred to me as man

Comment: Oh, my bad. I saw your jsFiddle and the html was not well formatted. I saw some code were it was not supposed to go. I wonder, if your actual page looks like this, this could be the reason of your error.

Comment: if you are talking about the "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...." that is below <div id="cuadro">, is beacause part of the table is in another page that i include... and even if you remove that(i prove it) the page is still not working...(if is something else tell me please, because i didn't see it)...

Comment: no te preocupes ya encontre el problema... mas abajo esta la razon de todo mi problema... gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.... and now everithing works perfectly.. this was my problem "`<?php echo $imag2; ?>`" in $imag2(and the other 3 $imag) i have "`<img class="difcursor" src="Imagenes/adelante.png" id="adelante" />`" i change this and now i don't have problems... some day i will understand why....(when i have more than 2 months using php and more than 2 weeks of JS)

Answer (score -1):

Try $('#lala'). I suppose you're using jQuery. $('#lala') means "select the element with the id 'lala'". $('lala') tries to get all the elements <lala> in the document, which of course don't exist.